# how to convert multiple variables column with 0 & 1 to yes & no in R

Tags: r, dplyr

newbie here still learning R.

I am trying to convert selective columns with 0 and 1 to either yes or no.

I am doing a novice way which is line by line

```
s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv <- s_r_data_no_na_split_rename %>%
  mutate(BPMeds = ifelse(BPMeds == "1","Yes","No"))

s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv <- s_r_data_no_na_split_rename %>%
  mutate(prevalentStroke = ifelse(prevalentStroke == "1","Yes","No"))

s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv <- s_r_data_no_na_split_rename %>%
  mutate(prevalentHyp = ifelse(prevalentHyp == "1","Yes","No"))

s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv <- s_r_data_no_na_split_rename %>%
  mutate(TenYearCHD = ifelse(TenYearCHD == "1","Yes","No")
```

but it dont seemed to work and only last selected variable column "TenYearCHD" was converted to yes/no.

[image: Code in R]

and how to convert all of them to factor at the same time? I only know how to do line by line.

```
s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$BPMeds <- as.factor(s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$BPMeds)
s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$prevalentStroke <- as.factor(s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$prevalentStroke)
s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$prevalentHyp <- as.factor(s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$prevalentHyp)
s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$TenYearCHD <- as.factor(s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv$TenYearCHD)
```

Comment: Because you overwrite `s_r_data_no_na_split_rename_conv` each time. Put all in one `mutate`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `across` to apply same function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
s_r_data_no_na_split_rename %>%
  mutate(across(c(BPMeds, prevalentStroke, prevalentHyp, TenYearCHD), 
                  ~factor(ifelse(.x == "1","Yes","No"))))
                  #Without ifelse
                  #~factor(c('No', 'Yes')[(.x == "1") + 1]))
```

In the earlier version of `dplyr` this was done using `mutate_at` :

```
s_r_data_no_na_split_rename %>%
   mutate_at(vars(c(BPMeds, prevalentStroke, prevalentHyp, TenYearCHD)), 
                  ~factor(ifelse(.x == "1","Yes","No")))
```

Answer (score 2):

`match` an assignment matrix to your data using `lapply`. *Example:*

```
dat
#           x0 X1 X2 X3
# 1  0.5390238  1  1  1
# 2  0.5802063  1  1  0
# 3 -0.6575028  0  1  1

FUN <- function(x) {
  m <- matrix(c(0, 1, "No", "Yes"), 2, 2)
  m[match(x, m[,1]), 2]
}

dat[2:4] <- lapply(dat[2:4], FUN)
dat
#           x0  X1  X2  X3
# 1  0.5390238 Yes Yes Yes
# 2  0.5802063 Yes Yes  No
# 3 -0.6575028  No Yes Yes
```

---

*Toy data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X0 = c(0.539023801893912, 0.580206320853481, -0.657502835154674
), X1 = c(1, 1, 0), X2 = c(1, 1, 1), X3 = c(1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                     -3L), class = "data.frame")
```